# XSLT foreach combined with recursion

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, foreach

I need to combine a foreach with a recursive solution that I wrote in XSLT.
The question is written below. It will be more clear when you read this post from top to bottom.

This is a XML example (the original XML is much bigger):

**XML**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <GetAllResponse xmlns="z">
            <GetAllResult xmlns:i="y" xmlns:a="x">
                <a:OrganisatieEenheden>              
                    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                        <a:Code>1</a:Code>
                        <a:Omschrijving>Niveau1</a:Omschrijving>
                        <a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1001</a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
                        <a:ParentCode i:nil="true"/>
                    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>              
                    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                        <a:Code>2</a:Code>
                        <a:Omschrijving>Niveau2</a:Omschrijving>
                        <a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1002</a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
                        <a:ParentCode>1</a:ParentCode>
                    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>     
                    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                        <a:Code>8</a:Code>
                        <a:Omschrijving>Niveau8</a:Omschrijving>
                        <a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1008</a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
                        <a:ParentCode i:nil="true"/>
                    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>             
                    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                        <a:Code>3</a:Code>
                        <a:Omschrijving>Niveau3</a:Omschrijving>
                        <a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1003</a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
                        <a:ParentCode>2</a:ParentCode>
                    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                    <a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                        <a:Code>4</a:Code>
                        <a:Omschrijving>Niveau4</a:Omschrijving>
                        <a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1004</a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
                        <a:ParentCode>3</a:ParentCode>
                    </a:OrganisatieEenheid>
                </a:OrganisatieEenheden>
            </GetAllResult>
        </GetAllResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Recursive XSLT**
(Additional information about the recursion can be found on the bottom of this post)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                   xmlns:i="y"
                   xmlns:a="x"
                   version="1.0"
                   exclude-result-prefixes="a i">
      <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:param name="crs" select="1004"/>
      <xsl:key name="org-by-crs"
               match="a:OrganisatieEenheid"
               use="a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr"/>
      <xsl:key name="org-by-code" match="a:OrganisatieEenheid" use="a:Code"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
         <OrganisatieEenheid>
            <Niveaus>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="key('org-by-crs', $crs)"/>
            </Niveaus>
            <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
               <xsl:value-of select="$crs"/>
            </OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
         </OrganisatieEenheid>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="a:OrganisatieEenheid">
         <xsl:if test="a:ParentCode[not(@i:nil='true')]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('org-by-code', a:ParentCode)"/>
            <xsl:text>::</xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="a:Omschrijving"/>
      </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output recursive XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrganisatieEenheid>
   <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2::Niveau3::Niveau4</Niveaus>
   <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1004</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
</OrganisatieEenheid>
```

I also have written the foreach function which take all the a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr

**foreach XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                   xmlns:i="y"
                   xmlns:a="x"
                   xmlns:ns2="z"
                   version="1.0"
                   exclude-result-prefixes="a i">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ns2:GetAllResponse/ns2:GetAllResult/a:OrganisatieEenheden/a:OrganisatieEenheid">
            <xsl:value-of select="a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr"/>  
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output foreach XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>10011002100810031004
```

**Question**

In the recursive function I give the a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr and that will result in 1 result.
Now I need a solution that does this for every a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr in the XML.
So I guess that I have to loop over all the numbers and perform the recursive over each number.

**Solution I need with the above XML example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrganisatieEenheden>
    <OrganisatieEenheid>
       <Niveaus>Niveau1</Niveaus>
       <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1001</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
    </OrganisatieEenheid>
    <OrganisatieEenheid>
       <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2</Niveaus>
       <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1002</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
    </OrganisatieEenheid>
    <OrganisatieEenheid>
       <Niveaus>Niveau8</Niveaus>
       <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1008</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
    </OrganisatieEenheid>
    <OrganisatieEenheid>
       <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2::Niveau3</Niveaus>
       <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1003</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
    </OrganisatieEenheid>
    <OrganisatieEenheid>
       <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2::Niveau3::Niveau4</Niveaus>
       <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1004</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
    </OrganisatieEenheid>
</OrganisatieEenheden>
```

**Additional information about the recursion**

Input: OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr -> 1004
The a:ParentCode and a:Code are a Parent - Child relationship

When your input is 1004 it searches al parents until a:ParentCode i:nil="true".
Then print all the Niveaus from top too bottom seperated by :: and also print the input value.

handy tool: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Thanks for thinking together with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need any loop.

Currently you apply your (perfectly correct) construct to *one* case. You only need to apply it to *all* cases. That means: get rid of the variable and you're done.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:i="y"
    xmlns:a="x"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a i"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key name="org-by-crs" match="a:OrganisatieEenheid" use="a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr"/>
  <xsl:key name="org-by-code" match="a:OrganisatieEenheid" use="a:Code"/>

  <xsl:template match="a:OrganisatieEenheden">
    <OrganisatieEenheden>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a:OrganisatieEenheid" />
    </OrganisatieEenheden>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:OrganisatieEenheid">
    <OrganisatieEenheid>
      <Niveaus>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('org-by-crs', a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr)" mode="niveaus" />
      </Niveaus>
      <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
        <xsl:value-of select="a:OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr" />
      </OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
    </OrganisatieEenheid>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:OrganisatieEenheid" mode="niveaus">
    <xsl:if test="a:ParentCode[not(@i:nil='true')]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('org-by-code', a:ParentCode)" mode="niveaus" />
      <xsl:text>::</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="a:Omschrijving" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result:

```
<OrganisatieEenheden>
   <OrganisatieEenheid>
      <Niveaus>Niveau1</Niveaus>
      <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1001</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
   </OrganisatieEenheid>
   <OrganisatieEenheid>
      <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2</Niveaus>
      <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1002</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
   </OrganisatieEenheid>
   <OrganisatieEenheid>
      <Niveaus>Niveau8</Niveaus>
      <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1008</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
   </OrganisatieEenheid>
   <OrganisatieEenheid>
      <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2::Niveau3</Niveaus>
      <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1003</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
   </OrganisatieEenheid>
   <OrganisatieEenheid>
      <Niveaus>Niveau1::Niveau2::Niveau3::Niveau4</Niveaus>
      <OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>1004</OrganisatieEenheidCrsNr>
   </OrganisatieEenheid>
</OrganisatieEenheden>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast respons! the answer was much simpler as I thought! Thx m8, you made my day.